# Postgres SSPI authentication on Windows

Tags: windows, authentication, postgresql, windows-authentication, postgresql-9.3

I'm trying to enable windows authentication for Postgresql 9.3 (Windows x64 *not in domain*, UAC is disabled, my account is local admin). The one click installer set the server running under `NETWORKSERVICE` which I think is fine. I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448778/how-can-i-configure-postgresql-to-use-windows-authentication) but it does not work:

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin>createdb --host=localhost testdb
Password:
Password:
createdb: could not connect to database template1: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

Created Login Roles named exactly as Windows account names - still no luck. What am I doing wrong? All the manuals I found on the net either obsolete or not applicable (require AD).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set the auth type to `sspi` in `pg_hba.conf` for the user/host/database combo you're using.

Comment: Thanks! Shouldn't this entry do the job: `host all all 0.0.0.0/0 sspi` ?

Comment: Yes, but perhaps another entry is matching first? Show the whole file.

Comment: My bad! I left the default entries uncommented. Now it's working just fine - God bless you!

Answer (score 4):

If anyone else encounters this like I did so starting from 9.5 you will need to add an optional parameter both to the ipv4 and ipv6 in order for this to work

include_realm=0

so the whole thing will look like

```
host all your_username 127.0.0.1/32 sspi include_realm=0
```

Comment: Reading about include_realm=0 in the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sspi-auth.html) and it's worth noting that "it is not secure in multi-realm environments unless krb_realm is also used".